# Prove by induction:

Tags: logic, induction

[image]

I have problems in the inductive step, it does not need 3 colors?

Comment: Can you write out what you think the inductive step should look like and why you think it should need three colors?

Comment: @SeanEnglish The induction is on the number of straight lines, suppose that for n straight lines it is true that the regions can be colored with two colors, if we add a straight line, we add n + 1 regions to the existing ones, but we could have triangles and This shape would be impossible to color it with 2 colors.

Comment: There is no problem with triangular regions. There definitely would be a problem if you had three regions that all share a common border, but that is different than a triangular region. With triangles, if they are blue, all their neighbors are red. That isn't an issue.

Comment: I think @Nash thinks that by 'regions' the problem refers to the segments formed by intersecting the lines instead of the 'polygons'.

Comment: If the colors are red and blue: when you add the $(n+1)$-st line to a properly colored plane divided up by $n$ lines, just flip the colors of all of the regions on one side of the line, from red to blue and from blue to red.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Explain a little better how this happens please

Comment: @Nash: See if the accepted answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122636/if-a-plane-is-divided-by-n-lines-then-it-is-possible-to-color-the-regions-for) helps.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, thank you very much!